# Allow specific domain through .htpasswd

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

For all the sites we develop, we use .htpasswd protection to stop bots and anyone without authorisation to access the staging environment. With the latest project we are working on, we are using [Resrc.it](http://www.resrc.it/) to handle our responsive images.

Resrc.it works by tunneling the images through their servers, and returning the correct sized image, so the URL's for the images look like this:

`http://trial.resrc.it/s=w240,pd1/o=85/http://staging.website.com/images/uploads/product/images/image.jpg`

The issue is that .htpasswd is blocking access so Resrc.it can't grab the images, I have tried adding `trial.resrc.it` to one of the domains allowed through but it's not working. This is my code so far:

```
SetEnvIf HOST "^(www\.)?website.local" dev
SetEnvIf HOST "^(www\.)?website.com" live
SetEnvIf HOST "^(www\.)?trial.resrc.it" resrcit
Order Deny,Allow

AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/website/staging/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
require valid-user

Deny from all
Allow from env=live
Allow from env=dev
Allow from env=resrcit
Satisfy any
```

Comment: Did you check from which server the request to the image originates? My assumption is that it’s not coming from `trial.resrc.it`.

Comment: Take a look in the Apache request log, and see where the request is actually coming from - could be that you need to whitelist their IP address instead.